# How to update records using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Hi i am trying to simple a web application using jsp,servlat and hibernate where i am trying to insert update and delete records i am getting problem when i am going to update  record

How can i achieve this

Here is my code
**updaterecprd.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
             HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
  String uname=httpSession.getAttribute("username").toString();
        String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
String  lname=request.getParameter("lname");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
String phone=request.getParameter("phone");
try
{
Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
    cfg.configure("/com/login/hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  

    //creating seession factory object  
    SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  
  Session sess = factory.openSession();
Transaction tr = sess.beginTransaction();
//cfg.configure("/com/login/hibernate.cfg.xml");
Contact c = (Contact)sess.get(Contact.class,fname);
c.setFname(fname);
c.setLname(lname);
c.setEmail(email);
c.setPass(pass);
c.setPhone(phone);
tr.commit();
sess.update(c);
sess.close();
out.println("<h1>Updated successfully!</h1>");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("e="+e.getMessage());
}
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {
       int id;
       String fname;
       String lname;
       String email;
       String uname;
       String pass;
       String phone;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
        }
```

i tried a lot but i am not able to achieve goal

How can i achieve my desired output

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to swap the 2 rows

```
tr.commit();
sess.update(c);
```

First you should store your changes via update(c) and after than commit them.

Comment: ANy errors? Is the Contact instance retrieved correctly? Which ID is retrieved from DB?

Comment: there is no error showing  retriving (uname)  from there

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with `(Contact)sess.get(Contact.class,fname);` The `Contact` entity is not loaded correctly. 
See [http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class), java.io.Serializable).

The `get()` method takes entity identifier as the  second argument in you case the `id` attribute and not the fname.
Also as susggested by @StanislavL change the sequence of commit and save.

Comment: You coould use somthing like `Query query = session.createQuery("from Contact where fname= :fname");  query.setParameter("fname", fname);`

Comment: This code is instead of session.get to read the `Contact`. Update part remains same.